# Python/Django: How to Prepend a # on to all URLS

Tags: python, django, mod-rewrite, redirect, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile web app with Django and jQuery Mobile. My problem is that jQuery Mobile likes for all links to be prepended with a ***#*** so it can accurately keep track of browsing history.

Example: http://www.fest.com/#/foo/1/

I would like know how to automatically redirect all urls that point **From:** /foo/1/ **To:** /#/foo/1/

If I don't do that and someone goes directly to ***/foo/1/***, then clicks a link pointing to ***/bar/2/***, they'll end up with a URL path like this:
***/foo/1/#/bar/2/***

I would very much like to prevent that from happening because its causes lots of problems. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: How are you currently building your URL's?  Can you provide a quote or a link to this "accurately keep track of browsing history" information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood what the # does.

The # in a URL is the "fragment" separator. *Nothing after that is sent to the server*. So there is no such URL as "foo. com#/foo" - as far as the server is concerned, it's just "foo.com". So you can't do any server-side redirection.

If your JS library is using the fragments to simulate navigation, you'll need to handle this with Javascript.

Comment: Well I guess you're right. Silly oversight on my part. *sigh* This is going to be a pickle to solve well.

Answer (score 0):

This is jquery mobile, so the answer is a bit different. Jquery mobile uses #something for history when working with AJAX. The AJAX call is introduced for every `<a href=...`

So you just link to a page like this: `<a href="some.html?var1=foo"` and JQM calls an ajax on it without reloading the page AND stores the item in the DOM document to not load again. The url is updated to have `#some.html` at the end and it's how the history is managed.

`<a href="#something"` WILL NOT work as in a normal page, because jquery mobile takes over.

Read here to get all info on links in jquery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/link-formats.html

Comment: But that wasn't the question. The OP wanted to know how he could redirect on the server side from URLs without a #, and my point was that he can't because you can't tell on the server.

Comment: @Andre - And what doest this bring into the matter? I did not say it's not. I just informed the OP that jquery mobile (hey, that's done with JavaScript too!) has its own use for the # in URLs. It obviously works with JavaScript and AJAX calls are done with JavaScript, because that's how JavaScript frameworks work.

Comment: @Daniel - OP had the problem with jqm prepending stuff with # and history management. I gave him the needed information so that he can use the framework correctly and possibly refactor the mechanizms in a way that he doesn't have the problem anymore.

Comment: @naugtur - See Daniel's answer. It explains clearly that this can not be done on the server, and that you must use Javascript.  Your answer starts by saying "the answer is a bit different" and then you start explaining how to do this on the client side with Javascript.

Comment: @Andre - I suggested using 0 lines of javascript. OP uses jquery mobile and it handles everything he needs in ONE particular way. I said he can't use #something in links that he produces. And using proper URLs fixes the server side dilemma. And yes, the change has to be done to the client side. That's as obvious as your first comment. [HTML is probably generated on the server side though, jquery mobile requires no javascript coding to work. I didn't assume where it is in my answer]

Comment: To be clear, @Daniel answered my question well. I was not asking how the jQuery Mobile framework's page navigation or history navigation worked.